# Как узнать uri смонтированной mongodb в docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

Как получить данные с смонтировнной в докере бд, или получить ее uri чтоб работать непосредственно с ней?

Comment: спросите у коллег/начальника.

Comment: Если бы все так было просто... Я единственный бекэндер, а фронтэндер недавно пришел. Тимлид он больше по софт части в комманде, так как он сишник)

Comment: дело в том, что нам, окружающим, ещё меньше вас известно, как именно там у вас настроена ваша инфраструктура вашими коллегами. поэтому, да: вам проще это узнать.